# SQLAchemy db.drop_all() gives AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing API with flask and it's various extensions. I have a database with set up connection to local MySQL database. When I am trying to execute `db.drop_all()`, the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 971, in drop_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'drop_all')
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 955, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4032, in drop_all
    tables=tables)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1940, in _run_visitor
    conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1549, in _run_visitor
    **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 121, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 909, in visit_metadata
    self.traverse_single(fkc)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 121, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 971, in visit_foreign_key_constraint
    self.connection.execute(DropConstraint(constraint))
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 948, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 68, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1003, in _execute_ddl
    if not self.schema_for_object.is_default else None)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 442, in compile
    return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 26, in _compiler
    return dialect.ddl_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 219, in __init__
    self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 245, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 1312, in visit_drop_constraint
    const = self.preparer.format_constraint(constraint)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 3151, in format_constraint
    return self.quote(constraint.name)
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 3101, in quote
    if self._requires_quotes(ident):
  File "/home/zahessi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 3072, in _requires_quotes
    lc_value = value.lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

The only thing that helps is to drop the entire database and then create it again. But I do this only via CLI, so there is no conventional method to do it in code.

EDIT: The db is initialized in this factory:

```
def create_app():
    from flask import Flask
    from models import db, ma
    from flask_compress import Compress
    from sqlathanor import initialize_flask_sqlathanor

    # initialization
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config.Config')
    db.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)
    initialize_flask_sqlathanor(db)
    Compress(app)

    # blueprints
    from blueprints.users_crud.views import MANAGE_USERS_BLUE
    from blueprints.projects_tasks.views import PROJECTS_BLUE
    app.register_blueprint(MANAGE_USERS_BLUE)
    app.register_blueprint(PROJECTS_BLUE)

    return app, db
```

As I tested the error doesn't depend in the extensions called here.
My goal is to delete all tables.

Comment: I think your question can be clearer if answers to these are edited in: How is `db` declared? Are you looking to drop tables or drop the database?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule updated the post.

Comment: Thanks. It seems one of the constraints defined in the model may be missing a name but this may point to a different issue with the way `db` is declared (See https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/50944e77522d4aa005fc3c833b5a2042280686d3/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L609). Are you running `db.drop_all()` within a Flask application context?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I do indeed. but how can you even declare a constraint without a name? All of my models are defined via classes, including the connection tables for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Surprise! Surprise! Looks like one is able to declare a constraint without a name and SQLAlchemy doesn't know about it. Some database engines automatically create a unique constraint name when one isn't given. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#configuring-constraint-naming-conventions. You can configure naming convention in Flask-SQLAlchemy as well or use a migration tool like Alembic for tracking constraint names https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/50944e77522d4aa005fc3c833b5a2042280686d3/docs/config.rst#using-custom-metadata-and-naming-conventions

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I checked all my tables - all of the constraints have unique names. And even after adding the naming convention as in example error still occurs.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Can you perhaps share a gist of the models, if you don't mind? I'll like to give a closer look to debug the code by reproducing this issue.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule here is a modified project https://github.com/zahessi/models_bug The bug still occurs though

Comment: At first, I wasn't able to run `flask db migrate` and had to initialize flask migrate in `app.py`. The `flask db upgrade` errored becaused `members` column in `Task` model ref'd a table that wasn't created yet. I specified that the foreign key constraint for the column should be created in an `ALTER` statement this way: `members = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users_to_tasks.id', ondelete="cascade", use_alter=True))`, the migration was then applied.  I started a shell using `flask shell`. In it, I wrote `from helper import create_app` ⏎  `db.drop_all()` ⏎. I didn't see any errors with it.

Comment: Usually though, when using flask_migrate, you want to run `flask db downgrade [revision]` to revert to a revision.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule But the column declaration which you used is identical with mine. and I am using flask-script in the file `manage.py`, so the migrations are handled via `python3 manage.py db migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Where a name isn't set for a constraint, SQLAlchemy doesn't create one for it and leaves the assignment of constraint name to the database. <sup>[[1]](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#configuring-constraint-naming-conventions)</sup>

Error with this approach occurs when executing a drop or alter statement on a table with a constraint created that way. This is because SQLAlchemy wouldn't know what name to resolve for the constraint. <sup>[[2]](https://github.com/zzzeek/alembic/blob/b9ef894de9bb2d5bb1198ed2d8350ef6e41bdba1/docs/build/naming.rst#the-importance-of-naming-constraints)</sup>

While it should be possible to reflect the tables and their foreign keys when deleting all tables in the following manner:

```
@manager.command
def dropdb():
    db.metadata.reflect(bind=db.engine)
    db.metadata.drop_all(db.engine)
```

For the MySQL dialect, foreign keys aren't reflected in the table and a `ForeignKeyConstraint` name needs to be specified when it's reflected. <sup>[[3]](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#reflection-of-foreign-key-constraints)</sup> This is how Alembic does it, when you look at the generated migration scripts.

In answer to your question, contraints need to be named.*e.g.*

```
class Branch(Base):
    //...
    project_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('projects.id', name="fk_branch_project_id_projects"))
```

It's a pain to do this for all the `ForeignKey` declared in the application models and SQLAlchemy provides a better way to provide a consistent naming convention. The naming convention to be used for constraints needs to be written in `models.py`. <sup>[[4]](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/50944e77522d4aa005fc3c833b5a2042280686d3/docs/config.rst#using-custom-metadata-and-naming-conventions)</sup>

```
#...
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, DateTime, MetaData

convention = {
  "ix": 'ix_%(column_0_label)s',
  "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
  "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
  "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s_%(referred_table_name)s",
  "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
}
metadata = MetaData(naming_convention=convention)
db = SQLAlchemy(model_class=FlaskBaseModel, metadata=metadata)
#...
```

In addition to this, I strongly suggest to use a migration tool like Alembic instead of dropping and creating all tables each time to apply changes to application models.